# Does using the UUID-PostgreSql data type solve performance issues?

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, uuid

I've read a lot of different opinions on the subject of "uuid as primary keys" and I'm a bit confused.

In particular, this article makes me unsure what's the best way:
https://tomharrisonjr.com/uuid-or-guid-as-primary-keys-be-careful-7b2aa3dcb439

**My use-case:**

I have a document table that has a 1 to n-association to document-records. I would like to use a UUID as the primary key in the document table. I will use the PostgreSql data type uuid
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html

Does this data type solve the performance concerns of this post?
Is it advisable to use a uuid at all for this use case?
The point of this would only be that the IDs cannot be guessed.

Comment: Impossible to answer since we don't know anything about the current performance of your queries. If your current query takes 5 milliseconds using integers, and a new query using uuid's is 10 times slower, would that be a problem? 50ms. And in my experience the biggest performance issues are not related to data types, but to the query itself. Especially the skills from the one who wrote the query and/or the data model and it's indexes

Comment: While using PostgreSQL `uuid` you at least avoid the text form of UUID (`uuid` is stored in hex as 16 bytes). The rest depends on your performance test. E.g. a hash join hash table will be larger, as the key is longer than if you use `int`. Ask if you have some advantage while using `uuid` over `int`. See similar discusion for [Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68573512/4808122)

Comment: The current performance is good. The project has just started. I don't want to experience any disadvantages in the future that will cause me difficulties. Better to make a correction at an earlier stage.

Comment: But I think that if guessability is the only reason to use uuid's, you should stick with integers and design the authorization accordingly so that guessability doesn't matter. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any serious arguments against UUIDs in the article you link to. As far as performance is concerned:

- it is slower to generate an UUID than to count up a sequence
- an `uuid` takes more storage space than a `bigint`
- most of all, a primary key index on an UUID will never perform as well during `INSERT`s, require more I/O and won't be as densely packed

But all these performance disadvantages are probably dwarfed by the rest of your processing: network latency, client application processing, etc. So don't worry too much.

My rule of thumb: if you need UUIDs because you generate primary keys in a distributed system or outside the database, do it. If you have no compelling reasons to use a UUID, use a an identity column.